# How do I assemble this using the following circuit?

Tags: arduino, resistors, schematics, ldr

I'm a third year Computer Science student and have decided to create a pulse sensor for my third year project. I'm mainly interested creating software to visualise results but I thought it would be cool to attempt to actually build the device also.

I'm *attempting* to follow [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/Homebrew-Arduino-Pulse-Monitor-Visualize-Your-Hear/?ALLSTEPS) guide but having difficulty reading this schematic: 
[image: Schematic]

So far, this is what I've come up with...

1) Connect 1 leg of the LDR to 6v power and the other leg to the base to base **(B)** of **Q1**.

2) Connect **C** of **Q1** to a 1k resistor and then connect that to my 6v (Unsure how I'd connect this to my 6v if the 6v is already connected to leg of LDR)

3) Connect Q1 (B) to R3 and then to ground.

From here I'm a little lost, would appreciate some advice.

I'm also a little confused to how I connect multiple things to ground/power. Will each connection have its own wire running to ground or do I need to create some sort of T like junction from the existing power/ground wire?

I've tried to give this a go in advance so I'm not just poaching for the answer but would appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google "solderless breadboard" or check this guy out: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-use-a-breadboard .  You'll do just fine.

Comment: You're using an LDR to detect a light pulse. That's fine but be aware that LDRs are very slow. My guess is that you'd need a pulse of at least half a second or more for the LDR to respond. If you use shorter pulses then ditch the LDR and use a photo diode or a photo transistor. You then also need a different circuit to amplify the signal from these devices.

Comment: it is components to use a thicker wire to connect ground connections, or a coomon point near battery - input , with radial connections (star ground) , but since all low current, just keep connections short and neat.

Comment: It doesn't matter how you route the connections to power, as long as all points that should connect to power do eventually make it there.  Likewise with Ground.

Comment: I *hate* to say it, but you might give Fritzing a go.  http://fritzing.org/projects/tutorial-1-building-a-circuit-on-breadboard  If you try this, you must *promise* to never ever post a fritzing breadboard instead of the lovely schematic you've given us!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Physical Connections do not have to look exactly same as logical connections shown in logic diagram as long as they match "logically"

The LDR is a photon current source that changes its effective resistance from >1M in dark to <<10K in bright light. ( they often have a dynamic range of 3-4 decades max, where as a Panasonic 5mm Light sensor has a dynamic range of 4-5 decades and is faster and FET buffered. (also cheap)

The LDR has a large area and thus more current can be captured but also large C, so the RC equivalent response time depends on light intensity and equivalent R with a fixed internal C, As stated by @FakeMoustache this causes slow response at high R values ( or light pulse turn off )

Since the supply shown here is 6V and the Vbe threshold is 0.6V, a 10:1 voltage divider is needed to activate Q1 , thus  trimpot of 10k+ for R1 determines this divide ratio is my suggestion.

i.e. if R1 is 5K and LDR is 50K it is almost low enough to turn on LED. If R1 is too high then ambient ceiling light will trigger it without a colour filter.  Usually IR emitters and IR detectors work better and faster with high gain Op Amps with a black optical daylight filter. But for ambient daylight the LDR is fine or an unfiltered (optical) Silicon PD (photo diode) is fine, but since smaller, it needs higher gain OpAmp but also,is faster since low C due to small size.

Since this is your 1st DIY, try to experiment and watch for false triggers from ceiling lights, with high R1.or too low R1 with light source too far away.

If you want a better light sensor design look up the Panasonic Light sensor 5mm at Digkey

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what OP is asking. :-)

No, you don't need to do "T" wires as the schematics seems to imply. You can take one end of R3 and both Es from Q1 and Q2, and twist them together. From electrical perspective this is equivalent, or even better. You can take upper ends of R1, R2, and LDR, and twist them together too. One advice though: assemble the whole thing first without the battery, and connect the battery (holder?) leads at the very end.

Comment: and double check before powering up pin polarity of all diodes , transistors and battery